# Testing Constructor with JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I need to test a constructor which throws an exception using JUnit.

Below is the constructor:

```
public EISThirdPartyClient(ClientConfiguration _config, String _serviceURL)
        throws EISClientException {
    super(_config, _serviceURL);

    try {
        ObjectMapperHolder.initialize(_config);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new EISClientException(e);
    }

}
```

Below is the test case:

```
@Test
public void testEISThirdPartyClientConctructor() throws EISClientException {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    EISThirdPartyClient client = new EISThirdPartyClient(new ClientConfiguration(), "url");

    boolean caughtException = false;
    try {
        ObjectMapperHolder.initialize(null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof EISClientException) {
            caughtException = true;
            assertTrue(ex.getCause() instanceof EISClientException);
        } else {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            fail("Uncaught exception");
        }
    }
    assertTrue(caughtException);
}
```

I am getting `java.lang.AssertionError`, which isn't what I'm expecting.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're testing the wrong thing - you want to ensure that the construction of your object fails, not that it bails out when `ObjectMapperHolder` bails out.

You can also greatly simplify the test - you can expect that `EISClientException` is thrown without needing to do **any further validation** of the exception.

The main point is to get the test to fail with the minimum required amount of work.  It *seems* that passing `null` as your configuration might do it, so here's an example with that:

```
@Test(expected = EISClientException.class)
public void testEISThirdPartyClientConctructor() throws EISClientException {
     new EISThirdPartyClient(null, "url");
}
```

If this doesn't quite suit your needs, you may want to look into a mocking framework like Mockito to provide behavior when you are in the critical section of your code.

Comment: Great. It went through. 

Thank you so much :)